# Hector import TimeUUIDSerializer can't be resolved

Tags: cassandra

I downloaded hector-core-0.8.0-2.tgz for the latest cassandra installed on my machine. When I am trying to import TimeUUIDSerializer in my class, I got the 'import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.TimeUUIDSerializer can't be resolved' error, but others just seems fine.

Though I do find it under https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/serializers.

Am I missing anything?

I am doing this in Eclipse.

```
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.TimeUUIDSerializer; // compile error!
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ColumnFamilyTemplate;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.template.ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;
```

Comment: are you sure that uuid-3.2.0.jar is in your classpath ?

Comment: I've seen eclipse get confused at times, try restarting eclipse, selecting the project and hitting F5 to refresh, then going project->clean->clean all projects

Comment: still not working. question is - if UUIDSerializer is there, why not TimeUUIDSerializer? Is hector-core-0.8.0-2 really has the class declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently posted this question to hector-users group (I didn't see this SO question at the time), and Ed Anuff posted that there is no need the special Time based serializer. Unfortunately, no other explanations. See discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hector-users/-derh77G_O4/discussion).